# BLE: How to send Write Request instead of Write Command?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I'm trying to send packets to bluetooth low energy (BLE) device from smartphone (Android App)

I know how to send Write Command:

something like this:

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
            for (final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : service.getCharacteristics()) {
                if (characteristic.getUuid().toString().equals(CONTROL_UUID)) {
                    boolean setValue = characteristic.setValue(new byte[]{/*..BYTES.*/});
                    boolean writeCharacteristic = gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

when I see this sent command in Wireshark (sniffing app), I see something like this

[image]

but I also need to send something like this (not **write command**, but **write request**)

[image]

official app which controls that devices sends this **write request** only once after connecting

seems without it I would not be able to control that device

so before I would send any **write command** I need to send this **write request** first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html#setWriteType(int)

You need to use the `WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT`.